# How to run configuration check test before testing everything else?

Tags: python, pytest

I'm using pytest.

After collecting tests I want to run configuration check test, if this test will fail then no other test should run at all.

Should I just throw an error in some pytest's configuration hook?

Comment: _I want to run configuration check test_ - can you elaborate a bit more on that? Is that another test case?

Comment: I'm not sure how it will look like. Either like "master test case"  which should run before everything else, or just configuration check which somehow stops tests execution (eg by throwing an error).

Comment: I would use a session-scoped fixture that calls [`pytest.exit()`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/reference.html#pytest-exit) on early errors, probably with a custom exit code if you want to use that from outside.

Comment: You can also write a custom hookimpl, presumably a `pytest_configure()` or `pytest_sessionstart()` or even a `pytest_collectreport()` if the check should happen after tests are collected, but there won't be much difference in the end, only some time saved b/c the test preparation phase won't be executed.